# Category attributes in collection without default value

Tags: magento-1.9, category, attributes, category-attribute

I created attribute `custom_attribute` for category with some default value.
If I save category(for example for store 26) with some value for this attribute I can get via:

`Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(12);` //example where you will get data for your category with this `custom_attribute` value

`But`, if you try to load category collection and even use `addAttriuteToSelect('custom_attribute')`, you won't get a it's `value` in case you didn't save for default store manually some value.

That's becuase if you look in `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Collection/Abstract.php` line `127`, you will see that they join table where store_id = 0. That's mean that you need to save category with your `custom_attribute` for default store.

I've quick idea via observer to assign attribute value for default store.

If there any more clean solutions?